# gem uninstall rails and it still exist , didn't installed but it said it did

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I git cloned an open source software and is currently planning to contribute to it. Originally I installed ruby 1.9.3 with rvm and installed gem install rails - which fetched version 4.0 (newest version)

I installed ruby 2.0 as well with rvm and did 'gem install rails' which also fetched me version 4.0

I was planning to installed ruby 1.9.3 with rails 3.2.13 - an older version of rails
to work with different software and switch between them using rvm

So since my open source software is written in 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.13, I tried
    gem uninstall rails 
and removed all the rails version 
but when I do 
    rails-v , 
it is still 4.0

I figured out from another question that there are folders associated with 4.0 that I need to remove to remove 4.0, another question suggest that I install rails 3.2.13 but when I make a new app I can just do rails 3.2.13 new app etc. I installed that under 1.9.3 when I switch to 2.00 which still has 4.0, I tried rails 3.2.13 new app and it ran which I don't think it should.

I am growing semi-frustrated with this, and I wish someone can help me while I browse even more questions.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a new gemset within rvm for this. That way you can use a different version of ruby and rails than your system default. Switch to ruby version 1.9.3 in RVM and then use `rvm gemset create <name-here>` and then `rvm gemset use <name-here>` to create and use the new gemset. Switch to the directory of the project you cloned and run `bundle install` to install all of the necessary gems, including rails (assuming the rails version is specified in the Gemfile.)